# Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups of order 4 and neither group contains an element of order 4. Show that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups of order 4 and assume further that neither group contains an element of order 4. Show that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Here is my attempt:

Let $G$ be a group order 4 which has no element of order 4. By Lagrange's theorem $o(g) \in $  {1,2,4}. Since there is no element of order 4, we have only 2 cases. If  $o(g) = 1$  , then $g = e$. On the other hand, if  $o(g) = 2$ ,  then $g \neq e$. So if $G$ equal to {a, b, c, d} then, $a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = d^2 = e$. Take $c = ab$. Since $c \neq a \neq b \neq e$ then, $a \leftrightarrow (1,0)$, $b \leftrightarrow (0,1)$ and $c \leftrightarrow (1,1)$.

Is my attempt correct? How can I finish the proof, and find the isomorphism? Any help would be great.

Comment: hint: a group of order $p^2$ , where $p$ is prime, is abelian so you can use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: You should easily be able to show that a group $G$ which satisfies $g^2=e$ for every element $g\in G$ is abelian (commutative): consider $(gh)^2=e$. Then the group is small enough that you can write out the group table and show that any other group of the same kind just has renamed elements (that is what an isomorphism is). Others are right that there are more powerful and more general results, but I am guessing you won't have got that far yet.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to check that you have a homomorphism. That's what I kind of don't like about it.

I much prefer to use a sledgehammer in these situations.   I happen to know there are only two groups of order $4$.  They're both abelian.   The smallest non-abelian group is $S_3$.

Then no element of order $4$ means $G$ is not cyclic.   The only remaining possibility is $V_4$, the Klein four group.

---

I also like the hint.  It's easy to show that a group of order $p^2$ is abelian.   Then use the structure theorem.